# Are two loops intersecting even number of times in the torus homologous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $K$ is a torus. Suppose $l_1$ and $l_2$ are simple closed curves in $K$ that  intersect transversely at even number of crossings. Then is it necessary that the closed curves $l_1$ and $l_2$ are homologous in the torus $K$?

Comment: Am I missing a something ? Consider the following case : $a$ is $\partial B(p,\epsilon)$ and $b$ is a generator $(0,1)\in \pi_1(K)$ such that they meet at two points.

Comment: I don’t understand what’s a?

Comment: $a$ is a simple closed curve.

Comment: I forgot to write the assumption that both loops are not trivial, I mean not homologous to zero

Comment: The exercise is true ? For instance curves representing $(2,1),\ (0,1)$ are not homologous.